# Counting Pairs in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I need to find out how many pairs exist for a value.

My table holds 3 cols like

```
+----+----------+------+-----------------+
| id | one      | two  | three           |
+----+----------+------+-----------------+
|  1 | steve    | bob  | michael         |
|  2 | bob      | steve| chris           |
|  3 | chris    | sam  | NULL            |
|  4 | michael  | chris| lea             |
|  5 | steve    | lea  | NULL            |
|  6 | susan    | chris| steve           |
|  7 | lea      | steve| bob             |
```

Now i'd like to for example find the pairs for steve incl their count ... col 3 is "optional" (can contain null) and "one" and "two" are always filled.

The result should look like: Steve & Lea 2, Steve & Bob 2, Steve & Chris 3, Steve & Michael 1, Steve & Susan 1 ...

EDIT: A better example (data-wise) would be:

```
+----+--------+--------+--------+--------+
| id | url    | color1 | color2 | color3 |
+----+--------+--------+--------+--------+
|  1 | foo.com| red    | grey   |        |
|  2 | a.com  | white  | red    | grey   |
|  3 | b.com  | black  | white  |        | 
|  4 | z.com  | white  | red    |        |
|  5 | 123.com| white  | grey   | black  |
```

color1, 2, 3 are the most prominent colors the site uses (at least 2, optional 3).
Result should be a list of the most common combinations for a color. Hope this examples makes more sense.

Comment: What do you mean by "pairs"?  What do you want your result to look like?

Comment: Pairs = Steve & Lea 2, Steve & Bob 2, Steve & Chris 3, Steve & Michael 1, Steve & Susan 1 ...

Comment: But not Steve & Steve? Also, why are Steve&Bob 2? Is Bob&Steve a different pair than Steve&Bob?

Comment: Sorry, Steve & Bob should be 3. If I had a script to count them, I wouldn't make any mistakes counting them myself :)

Comment: Please show your working so far, and identify the steps in it that are causing you trouble.

Comment: But still, based on what logic. If I match every column with every other, assuming the names of a pair would be different, I still could make a dozen of combinations of different Steves and Bobs. By far the largest part of writing a query is clearly define the rules. The rest is just syntax.

Comment: I'm currently working with arrays to count them (with 3 selects to fill the arrays), but I'd like to count them via MySQL without using any arrays in PHP

Comment: GolezTrol: please presume that those names are unique, so there's only one Steve, Michael, Bob and so.

Comment: If anything in your question is incorrect, feel free to edit your question. Right now, I think you've got everyone really confused!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure, if I understood your question correctly, but given this sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE t
    (`id` int, `one` varchar(7), `two` varchar(5), `three` varchar(7))
;

INSERT INTO t
    (`id`, `one`, `two`, `three`)
VALUES
    (1, 'steve', 'bob', 'michael'),
    (2, 'bob', 'steve', 'chris'),
    (3, 'chris', 'sam', NULL),
    (4, 'michael', 'chris', 'lea'),
    (5, 'steve', 'lea', NULL),
    (6, 'susan', 'chris', 'steve'),
    (7, 'lea', 'steve', 'bob')
;
```

I get with this query

```
select
least(a, b) as p1, greatest(a, b) as p2, count(*)
from (
select
one as a, two as b
from
t
where 'steve' in (one, two)
union all
select
one, three
from
t
where 'steve' in (one, three)
union all
select
two, three
from
t
where 'steve' in (two, three)
) sq
group by p1, p2
```

this result:

```
|      P1 |     P2 | COUNT(*) |
|---------|--------|----------|
|  (null) | (null) |        1 |
|     bob |  steve |        3 |
|   chris |  steve |        2 |
|     lea |  steve |        2 |
| michael |  steve |        1 |
|   steve |  susan |        1 |
```

Is this what you're looking for?

- Play around with it in this [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5c25e/3/0)

Comment: Looks good, but since my query data is a little bit more complex I have to try it with my real data first, but since it's working for the example it should be the solution I was looking for

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT
    CONCAT(one, " & ", two), count(*)
FROM
    myTable
GROUP BY
    1
```